# Install Maven2 on Karmic

Tags: java, maven-2, ubuntu-9.10

Is there a .deb for Maven2 on Karmic Koala? I see maven2, but it has 100+MB of dependencies (!). Is there a package that is only mvn and none of those dependencies?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only .deb that exists is the one you are seeing in the repositories. So if you want to install it with `apt-get`, you have to install all dependencies as well.

Personally, I've chosen to install it manually (mostly because Maven was broken in the RC of Karmic until they upgraded it to version 2.2.1 and because I'm now swapping between maven 2.x and maven 3.x). To do so, follow these steps:

1. Download a Maven archive from the [official website](http://maven.apache.org/).
2. Unzip it somewhere on your file system (I'm using `/opt/apache-maven-2.2.1` which is symlinked as `/opt/maven`).
3. Then `export M2_HOME=/opt/maven` (for example in your `~/.profile`).
4. Finally, add `$M2_HOME/bin` to your `PATH` (for example in your `~/.profile`).

Comment: Yes, Pascal is very right here.   The recommended way to install Maven on any Linux platform is exactly the process he outlined.   The distributions try to do too much fancy acrobatics with the Maven repository, you can almost always assume that they've done something wrong.   Cheers.